Get percentages in query

Thank you for your assistance.
I can't get it to divide? Is it because its the Modulo operator?
I've reviewed and scoured the web for a bit, but it just doesn't seem to be working.
How do I get a percentage in SQL Server. I attempting to divide, but it just spits out nothing.

As per the How do I ask a good question? guide, DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

look up "integer division"

after looking into integer division also watch out for NULLs (any division involving a NULL is NULL)

Don't abuse select distinct, there is simply no need for it here (and in many many other cases, use sparingly).
Also, it is not necessary to run 3 separate subqueries to arrive at the figures you need. Instead use "conditional aggregates" which is basically putting a case expression inside the aggregation function.
Then, a quick fix for the integer division problem is to explicitly convert integers to decimals, or implicitly make into decimals by using multiplication by a decimal e.g
select
      count(case when Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) as male_count
    , count(case when Gender = 'Female' then 1 end) as female_count
    , count(*) as total_count
    , count(case when Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as male_pct
    , count(case when Gender = 'Female' then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as female_pct
from MedMal85

